# Getting first onNext signal from list of Mono

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Consider there are 3 functions that results in `Mono<Int>`s. I am trying to get the first result emitted by any of the Monos. Here's a test to describe what I am looking for:

```
fun main() {
  StepVerifier
    .create(firstElement())
    .expectSubscription()
    .expectNext(3)
    .expectComplete()
    .verify()
}

fun firstElement(): Mono<Int> = Flux.concat(_1(), _2(), _3(), _4()).next()

fun _1(): Mono<Int> = 1.toMono().delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
fun _2(): Mono<Int> = Mono.empty()
fun _3(): Mono<Int> = 3.toMono().delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(500))
fun _4(): Mono<Int> = Mono.error(RuntimeException())
```

The question is in `firstElement()`, how to result in `3` since it's the first to emit an element. But, as you can see, from any of the Monos:

- It's possible that any of them could emit faster than the rest
- It's possible that any of them could emit empty or `onComplete()`
- It's possible that any of them could emit error or `onError()`

I have tried several operators:

- `Mono.zip {...}` requires all of them to emit, because the return is `Tuple<Int!>`
- `Mono.first(...)` and `Flux.first(...).next()` transmits `onComplete()` and/or `onError()`
- `Flux.concat(...)` eliminates `onComplete()` and `onError()` but it's still sequentially subscribing based on the order of the given `Publisher<T>`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could resume on error with empty `Mono` and merge your functions

```
private Mono<Integer> firstElement() {
    return Flux.merge(
            _1().onErrorResume(ignored -> Mono.empty()),
            _2().onErrorResume(ignored -> Mono.empty()),
            _3().onErrorResume(ignored -> Mono.empty()),
            _4().onErrorResume(ignored -> Mono.empty()))
            .next();
}
```

Comment: this is perfect!
i was too focused on finding a single function to solve this, but a simple composition like this worked like a charm!